# Why does Math.imul return this value?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(-559038841 * 2654435761); //returns -1483932691338393000

console.log(Math.imul(-559038841 , 2654435761)); // returns 1445956183.
```

I expected the two to have the same - value but they do not. Why is this?

I imagine this has to do with the 32-bit nature of math.imul but not sure.

Comment: You forgot some languages:  C# and Java.  BTW, this is not C because the C language does not have the *object.method()* syntax.  Standard C++ doesn't have the `console` object.  What language are you programming in?  Also, Standard C++ doesn't have the `Math` object nor the `imul` function.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, see [numeric limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Comment: Sorry about that. when I was researching math.imul I read that it uses c-style 32-bit multiplication which is why i used that tag. its in javascript

Comment: Fundamentally, there are two types of integral (integer) multiplication:  multiplication where the values fit into the processors registers, and multiplication that requires more than one register.  Since you tagged as C and C++, tell the compiler to print out the assembly language.  The truth is in the assembly language.

Comment: For example, see [ARM processor multiplication instructions](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/ARM-Instruction-Reference/ARM-multiply-instructions).

Comment: Hmm I'm still a bit confused. C and C++ tags were done by mistake and removed.

Is the value too large to fit in the processors register? How does it handle the function if it is? Why did it arrive at 1445956183?

Comment: This behaviour is the explicit purpose of `Math.imul`, so I’m surprised you found `Math.imul` but still expected the two to have the same value. Yes, it has to do with its 32-bit overflow behaviour.

Comment: Any idea where I can find documentation on its 32-bit overflow behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-math.imul), `Math.imul` not only converts its opreands to unsigned 32-bit integers before performing the multiplication, but also limits the result to a 32-bit integer by performing `modulo 2^32` on the result[1]. So the end result cannot be bigger than `2^32 - 1` which equals `4294967295`.

After that, it also converts it to a signed integer by treating the most significant bit as a sign bit, so the actual end result is between `-(2^31)` and `2^31 - 1`, or between `-2147483648` and `2147483647`

[1] I suppose that in practice the engine simply drops the extra bits and keeps the less significant 32 bits. But the effect is the same as performing modulo 2^32.